# What is the simplest way for me to use ES6 modules and also npm modules using the import/export syntax?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, browserify, es6-modules

ES7 Modules have become almost universally supported in the browser today. Old solutions to this problem seem to have involved using babel with either Browserify or Webpack. Is this still the simplest adequately supported way to use ES6 import/export syntax for both local and npm modules?

Edits: Was a rant. Distilled it.

Comment: because there are some people that uses browsers that dont support `import / export`

Comment: I'm voting to close this because this reads more like a rant than a specific question. If there's a real question here, try taking out all opinions and bonus content and distill it to a simple question. If not, perhaps this is a good topic for a blog post

Comment: That's fair enough. I know there's a question in there somewhere I'm just having a really hard time distilling it. I promise I didn't just want to rant (even if it did feel kind of good.)

Comment: Okay I tried to get rid of the rant and cut it down to just the question.

Comment: Afaik browsers still don't support "useful" module identifier resolution (although [import maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps) are being worked on), and unless you've set up a HTTP2 server knowing about your modules' dependencies you'll still want to serve a bundle instead of each module file individually (and pretty surely you wouldn't want to just serve your `/node_modules` folder)

Answer (score 2):

> **TLDR: Using bundler is still the best way to ship/package your application.**

It is not just the question of module. It has more to do with server topology and overall bundling.

For example, you have some third party `npm` module which is provides as ES module aka `import/export` syntax. It will be typically installed within the `node_modules` folders and so will its dependencies. Now, you are going to use this module in your code, you would want to use it like

```
import xyz from 'my-npm-module';
```

With the above simple statement, there are multiple issues. Above type of import is **non-relative** import. For Node.js or bundlers like Webpack or Rollup, this is a simple matter of looking into `node_modules` folder starting from current directory and finding all the way up till the root partition.

Now browsers have no such knowledge of **non-relative** import resolution (Browsers do not use Node style module resolution). So, first question is how would a browser know that where to look for such modules on the server. Second question, assume that somehow you teach browser to use **non-relative** modules and follow Node style resolution algorithm, you would still need to package entire `node_modules` folder including sub-directories. This is very cumbersome process and needlessly inflating your final build size of the application.

These are the reasons why you still need to use bundler like Webpack and Browserify. To keep things lean, you may skip Babel if you don't want to support old JS engines. However, if you really want to use and ship ES modules to the browser, consider using `Rollup.js` which supports output format as `ES module` as against Webpack's `UMD` or `Common.js`.

Another alternative that you can consider using `System.js` + `JSPM` way of bundling application where `ES modules` are defaults but it does not offer flexibility like that of Webpack or Rollup. Also, there is a new bundler - `Parcel.js` which aims to be zero config solution and is very easy to use. You won't notice all the complex belts and whistles.

> In the end, real world front-end bundling is not just about JavaScript. There are other assets like TS files, ReasonML files, Images, SVG files which you might want to transpile and bundle with final bundle with using advanced optimizations like Tree shaking, HMR (dev mode) where bundles really excel at.

Comment: Thanks, this illuminates a lot. I'm really loving using Parcel and I have a better understanding of why the more complex bundlers are still needed.

Why do I have to use non-relative importing though? I'd be super happy with the simplicity of just using

```import xyz from '..node_modules/my-npm-module';```

Why is this not possible?

Comment: > Browsers do not use Node style module resolution

Well that's the issue right there. They should, and somebody should write a shim that will FUCKING FORCE browsers to use Node style module resolution.